# flutter channels replace each others

Tags: flutter, flutter-channel

why **flutter** store the **SDK** **locally** for just **One channel** and replace **ALL SDK** when **switching** the channel?
why **flutter** does not save **ALL downloaded SDK**, what is the **problem**, why I have to wait for switching?
thanks

Comment: This is not a question for StackOverFlow. You should be asking that over Slack, Github and other platforms as these kind of question are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

See https://pub.dev/packages/fvm: *Flutter Version Management: A simple cli to manage Flutter SDK versions*.  As for why, it's really not much of an inconvenience.  If you switch to the git-based checkout of the Flutter repo, the switch between channels is just a "git branch" change away, so the expense really isn't there.

Comment: thanks for your replay, I will try git-based version, but is there any problem with it while upgrading?